# How many possibilities would you have in an android lock pattern, always using all 9 moves?

Tags: combinatorics

We are doing some research and wanted to know how many possibilities you would have if you would use all 9 dots/options in an (android) swipe lock pattern.

What would the formula be to get to this answer? How? Could someone provide a nice explanation as well? We would like to understand it and explain it ourselves.

Thank you ( didn't know which specific tags to pick )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979524/android-lock-password-combinations

Comment: I am a programmer, so my solution would be "brute force" - generating all patterns and counting them :)

Comment: by possibilities do you mean number of straight lines or different number combinations?

Comment: if it's number of straight lines, the minimum is four to cross all nine numbers.

Comment: different combinations, but making use of all the dots on the screen with every pattern. So minimum requirement: use all 9 dots on the screen, all possible combinations :)